# faces.size() has to be divisible by getFaceElementSize()

Tags: java, javafx, 3d, geometry, shapes

I'm trying to draw model using `TriangleMesh`.

```
TriangleMesh cubeMesh = new TriangleMesh();
ArrayList<Float> v = new ArrayList<Float>();
ArrayList<Float> vt = new ArrayList<Float>();
ArrayList<Float> vn = new ArrayList<Float>();
ArrayList<Integer> f = new ArrayList<Integer>();
objParser(v,vt,vn,f);

int s = v.size(); float[] points = new float[s]; for(int i = 0; i < s; i++) points[i] = v.get(i);
int s1 = vt.size(); float[] texCoords = new float[s1]; for(int i = 0; i < s1; i++) texCoords[i] = vt.get(i);
int s2 = vn.size(); float[] normals = new float[s2]; for(int i = 0; i < s2; i++) normals[i] = vn.get(i);
int s3 = f.size(); int[] faces = new int[s3]; for(int i = 0; i < s3; i++) faces[i] = f.get(i);
cubeMesh.getPoints().addAll(points);
cubeMesh.getTexCoords().addAll(texCoords);
cubeMesh.getNormals().addAll(normals);
cubeMesh.getFaces().addAll(faces);
MeshView meshView = new MeshView(cubeMesh);
Group gr = new Group(meshView);
Camera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
Scene scene = new Scene(gr, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
scene.setFill(Color.SILVER);
scene.setCamera(camera);
primaryStage.setTitle("3D");
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```

`objParser` method:

```
private void objParser(ArrayList<Float> v, ArrayList<Float> vt,ArrayList<Float> vn,ArrayList<Integer> f){

    try {
        File file = new File("C:\\model\\source\\MesaF\\edgy.obj");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            String[] strArr = line.split(" ");
            if (strArr[0].equals("v")) {
                for (int i = 1; i < strArr.length; i++) {
                   v.add(Float.parseFloat(strArr[i]));
                }
            } else  if (strArr[0].equals("vt")) {
                for (int i = 1; i < strArr.length; i++) {
                    vt.add(Float.parseFloat(strArr[i]));
                }
            } else if (strArr[0].equals("vn")) {
                //String strArr[] = line.split(" ");
                for (int i = 1; i < strArr.length; i++) {
                    vn.add(Float.parseFloat(strArr[i]));
                }
            } else if (strArr[0].equals("f")) {
                String forF = line.substring(2);

                String strF[] = forF.split(" ");
                for (int i = 0; i < strF.length;i++) {
                    String strFF[] = strF[i].split("/");
                    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                        f.add(Integer.parseInt(strFF[j]));
                    }
                }
            }
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
    } catch (
            IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

After running program i only see silver background and this message in console:

```
PM javafx.scene.shape.TriangleMesh validateFaces
WARNING: faces.size() has to be divisible by getFaceElementSize().
```

Can someone help with fixing this issue?

Blank screen: [start screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBlfN.png)

Just want to see model on the screen.

Comment: Edit your question to include the code for the `objParser` method.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.